# cocos2dx, google payment crush

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I use cocos2d-x 2.2.6 to code a game app.
The app follows these step during purchasing Google payment.

```
1.Open a Google payment dialog.
2.A "Payment Succeed" from Google will show out if the purchase is successful. Then the client receive the purchase information and send it to our server to verify.
3.Show some dialog at client about the result. If you failed to verify the purchase, a error dialog will show out. The dialog in this step is coded by ourself with cocos2d-x
```

I find out a case in step 3.

If I push home button to step back to the main page of the device and disconnect the internet when the "Payment Succeed" dialog in step 2 shows out. The app will crush when I reenter the app in some devices or the dialog will become a black area with nothing else(but the function is still available).

I wonder if it is a bug of cocos2d-x in Android devices, or just a bug created by myself.

Comment: Did you test using breakpoints?

Comment: I export an APK to do the test of course. The google payment won't be available while using debug mod.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do OpenGL operations(rendering a sprite in cocos2dx by way of add Child) on the main thread. When the call goes from Java to C++ it is not on the main thread. Try scheduling a function in c++ and do the rendering in that function.